# Is this still a class variable?

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I understand class variables should start with `@@`. Now I have this class:

```
class C
  @v = "my variable"

  def self.get_v
    @v
  end
end

puts C.get_v  #returns "my variable"
```

Is `@v` still a class variable? But its not having `@@`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the introspection as below, you would get the answer:

```
class C
  @v = "my variable"

  def self.get_v
    defined? @v
  end
end

puts C.get_v  #=> instance-variable

class C
  @v = "my variable"
  def self.get_v
    self.instance_variables
  end
end

puts C.get_v  #=> @v
```

It means `@v` is *class instance variable*.

```
class C
  @v = "my variable"
  def self.get_v
    self.new.instance_variables
  end
end

p C.get_v  #=> []
```

This is because `@v` is not *instance variable* of the instances of `class C`.

Same introspection you can do for the class variables also:

```
class C
  @@v = "my variable"
  def self.get_v
    defined? @@v
  end
end

p C.get_v  #=> "class variable
```

*In summary I can say ask the question to your object as above, it has the answers for you.*

Comment: @Bala Edited again. Hope it will help you! :)

Answer (score 5):

No, it is a *class instance variable*, i.e. an *instance variable* of the class object `C`.

The difference between the two is that the former is visible inside all the classes of a hierarchy, the latter is visible only inside the class that defines it. A simple example to (I hope) explain:

```
class A
  @a = 0  # class instance variable
  @@b = 1  # class variable
end

class B < A
  @a = 1
  @@b = 2
end

puts A.a # => 0
# the definition of @@b inside B have altered the value
# inside A. It's not the case for @a.
puts A.b # => 2
```

Comment: I have mixed feelings about the name "class instance variable". On one hand: it's a regular instance variable. No need to append "class" modifier. On the other hand, we need a way to differentiate this ivar from ones on an instance of this class.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a class variable. It's a regular instance variable. But it belongs to an instance of `Class` object. It's important not to confuse the two.